# Angular & Observable debounceTime

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, debouncing

Into an Angular 4 project, I have a function (let's call it `reload()`) that could be called by other functions (let's call them `A()` and `B()`) at any time. I would like to debounce the execution of `reload()` till X time (ie. msecs) passed from the last call of `A()` or `B()`. I was taking a look at the `Rx.Observable.debounce` and `Rx.Observable.debounceTime` functions but I did not understand if they really can help me with that or not.

An example:

```
time 0ms: A() gets executed and it calls reload()
time 200ms: B() calls executed and it calls reload()
Since X is set to 500ms, reload() should be called only once and after 500ms.
```

Comment: Is `throttleTime` what you're looking for?

Comment: @msanford Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a `Subject` with `debounceTime`. So have both functions `A` & `B` send a value to the subject. Then debounce the subject stream so only values are emitted after x time has passed.

```
// component.ts
subject$ = new Subject();
stream$;

constructor(){
    this.stream$ = this.subject$.debounceTime(1000);
}

A(){
    this.subject$.next('some value');
}
B(){
    this.subject$.next('some value');
}

ngOnInit(){
    this.stream$.subscribe(res => {
        this.reload();
    });
}
```

Here is a [stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yxcgkm?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) demoing this.